# ToolbarItem bottomBar

Tags: swiftui

swift ui で

ToolbarItem で

右下に設定したい場合に

ToolbarItem(placement: .bottomBar)

とすると

表示されません。

どうしたらいいでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NavigationStack系の下で宣言されている必要があります。

```swift
struct ContentView: View {  
  var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
      Text("Hello")
        .toolbar {
          ToolbarItem(placement: .bottomBar) {
            Button("Button") {}
          }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: 追記です。NavigationView { 下で Trailing closure passed to parameter of type 'Visibility' that does not accept a closure というアラートが表示 されて、使えません。